# Proving any biholomorphic self-map of the upper half-plane takes the form $z\mapsto \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb R$ and $ad-bc=1$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to prove using [the Schwarz-Pick theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Schwarz%E2%80%93Pick_theorem) that any conformal/biholomorphic self-map of the upper half-plane has the form \begin{equation}z \mapsto \frac{az+b}{cz+d}\tag{1}\end{equation} where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb R$ and $ad-bc=1$.

I see that there is an 'outline' on how to prove this on this same Wikipedia article, but it doesn't help me understand what I'm doing wrong (and I also don't follow why it is true that $|f'(z)| / \Im f(z) \leq 1/\Im z$). This is what I have so far:

Let $f$ be a biholomorphic self-map of the upper half-plane $\mathbb H$. Then we know that $\psi(z) = \dfrac{z-i}{z+i}$ maps $\mathbb H$ conformally onto the unit disk $\mathbb D$ and its inverse $\psi^{-1}(z) = - i \dfrac{z+1}{z-1}$ maps $\mathbb D$ conformally onto $\mathbb H$. The composition map $g := \psi \circ f \circ \psi^{-1}$ will therefore be a conformal map from $\mathbb D$ to itself. By Schwarz-Pick, we see that for any $a_1,a_2,z \in \mathbb D$,
$$
\left| \frac{g(a_1)-g(a_2)}{1-\overline{g(a_1)} g(a_2)} \right| \leq \left| \frac{a_1-a_2}{1-\overline{a_1} a_2} \right| \quad \text{and} \quad \left| g'(z) \right| \leq \dfrac{1-|g(z)|^2}{1-|z|^2},
$$
and if there is equality for either, then $g(z) = \omega \dfrac{z-a}{1-\overline{a} z}$ where $|\omega|=1$ and $|a|<1$.

Using the compositions, I get
$$ 
\psi\circ f(z) = \psi\circ f \circ \psi^{-1} (\psi(z)) = \omega \frac{\psi(z)-a}{1-\overline{a}\psi(z)} = \omega \frac{(1-a)z-(1+a)i}{(1-\overline{a})z+(1+\overline{a})i},
$$
and thus
$$
f(z) = \psi^{-1} \left(\omega \frac{(1-a)z-(1+a)i}{(1-\overline{a})z+(1+\overline{a})i}\right).
$$
I tried applying the definition of $\psi^{-1}$ to this but I don't get anything that simplifies to be the form of (1). Is this not the correct approach? The outline on Wikipedia seems to insist that this should be a trivial thing, but I don't see it.

Comment: You've proven that $f$ has to be a fractional linear transformation. One thing you could do now, is to argue that $f$ maps the extended real line to itself, and then argue this implies the coefficients of $f$ have to be real (this ought to be the case since the extended real line is exactly the real projective line).

Comment: a detail, the result is true only after you say: we will multiply all the coefficients by a complex number with $|\omega| = 1$   so as to force $a$  to be nonzero and real, or (when $a=0$)  to force $b$   nonzero and real